# Spring ignoring @Qualifier in very simple program

Tags: java, spring

I have Circle class:

```
public class Circle
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("pointA")
    private Point center;

    public Point getCenter()
    {
        return center;
    }
    public void setCenter(Point center)
    {
        this.center = center;
    }
}
```

point class:

```
public class Point
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY()
    {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

And my spring xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
        >

       <bean id="pointA"  name="pointA" class="SpringTest.Point">
            <qualifier value="pointA"/>
            <property name="x" value="4"/>
            <property name="y" value="4"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="pointB" name="pointB" class="SpringTest.Point">
              <property name="x" value="2"/>
              <property name="y" value="5"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="circle" class="SpringTest.Circle">
       </bean>

       <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

As far as I am concerned this should work like this:
1. Spring see @Autowire annotation
2. Spring realizes that there are many beans of Point type
3. Spring uses @Qualifier annotation to determine which bean to inject

Unfortunaltely it is not working like that.
While executing:

```
AbstractApplicationContext abstractApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
BeanFactory beanFactory = abstractApplicationContext.getBeanFactory();
```

I am getting an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'circle': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private SpringTest.Point SpringTest.Circle.center; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [SpringTest.Point] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: pointA,pointB
```

I am beginner at spring topic but I believe @Qualifier annotation should do the job and determine which bean to use.

Startup log:
https://gist.github.com/mmajews/384207ee97b2cc8bd49a

Comment: Yes, that should work correctly (though using Java-based configuration is a lot easier than the XML you're using). Please post the version of Spring you're using, as well as startup logs at DEBUG level.

Comment: @chrylis Spring version is 4.1.2.RELEASE. How can I get the startup logs ?

Comment: How are you running the application? Generally, you'd configure your logger (log4j or logback) to output messages from `org.springframework` at DEBUG.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ to run my simple app. Ok I will take a look and try to run this logger.

Comment: But how are you launching it--as a Web application? Using Spring Boot? Manually with a `main` method?

Comment: I have a main method with two lines of code that is placed in my post. I simply click run Main and that is all and I got the output in console.

Comment: It *should* work, and I'd have to see the startup logs for the context to have any shot at figuring out what's going on. FWIW, qualifier configuration in XML seems always to have been a little flaky.

Comment: Oh, I just realized you have an *all*-XML configuration. Add `<context:annotation-config/>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `<context:annotation-config/>` in your spring xml, rather than instantiating the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, as that does not handle `@Qualifier` annotations.

Or, if you really want to control everything that gets instantiated in your context, have a look at the actual [candidate resolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/QualifierAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.html) for `@Qualifier`.

Answer (score -3):

You have to make your `Point center` public:

`public Point center;`

Spring only has access to public properties an methods.

Comment: Spring and every other CDI container will autowire private fields.